# How to update database dynamically in mvc 4

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a database table that has 2 columns. One called Start Date, the other one End Date. Where I could possibly run some check to compare this dates and if End Date = DateTime.Now than Delete the row where I have this End Date. That should happen without any user interaction.

Comment: Better go for window services or if you want to make it more friendly refer this link http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx

Comment: I have other question relating this. If I run this background worker every second how bad this will be for the overall result? I guess every request will happen when the worker release the resources, not quite sure about this:)

Comment: If you want to give more importance to the performance better try the window services instead of background task.

Comment: You could try preparing up something similar to `schedulers` or `task schedulers` which run periodically over time async without user interaction.